# boost::odeint not working as intended (pass arguments of system function by reference!)

Tags: boost, odeint

I'm trying to use `boost::odeint` inside one of my class's member functions in a .cpp file. My class is called OdeDriver and the member is :

```
ublas::matrix\<double\> OdeDriver::RungeKuttaStep(
const ublas::vector\<double\> &U,
const ublas::vector\<double\> &alphas,
const int &step){...}
```

I'm doing the following inside this member function inside a for loop:

```
state_type x0 = {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
auto lambda = \[\](const state_type x, state_type dxdt, const time_type t)
{
dxdt = {1, 1, 1, 1};
};
stepper_type rk;
rk.do_step(lambda, x0,0.0, 0.1);
```

where I have defined the above types in a separate .hpp file as:

```
typedef std::vector\<double\> state_type;
typedef odeint::runge_kutta4\<state_type\> stepper_type;
```

The problem is that x0 is not updating, it should be `x0 = {0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2}`. I have noticed that inside the do_step function, after calling `sys( x , m_dxdt.m_v ,t )`, the class property `m_dxdt.m_v` is not updated to the value `{0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1}` even though the system function is working as intended. Somehow, the system function output is not being copied to `m_dxdt.m_v`.

If i run this same code on the main function, everything works as intended (I haven't tried running the exact code above, but I can use `boost::odeint` in the main() with no problems).

Can you tell me what's wrong?

---

Answer (score 0):

While I was writing my question I realized what I was doing wrong, so I decided to post my question and answer it myself since I spent a long time trying to figure this out.

For some reason, I thought that passing a `std::vector<double>` to a function was always passed by reference. That is,

```
void foo(std::vector<double> v){...}
```

would pass `v` by reference to `foo`.

The fix is I have to pass the arguments to my `lambda` function by reference using `&`.

But am I wrong in assuming that passing a `std::vector<double>` to a function without using the `&` passes the vector by reference?